# Java - Compare two fields using only comparable interface

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I'm trying to compare two fields (string and integer) using only the Comparable interface. It was my first time using this and I've no idea where to put the second field to compare the values.

```
public int compareTo(Object o) throws ClassCastException
{
    int count = 0;
    int compareName = this.lastName.compareTo(((SalePerson) o).getLastName());
    int compareSales = Integer.compare(this.totalSales, ((SalePerson) o).getTotalSales());

    if(!(o instanceof SalePerson))
    {
        throw new ClassCastException("A SalePerson object expected.");
    }

    if((this.totalSales < ((SalePerson) o).getTotalSales()))
    {
        count = -1;
    }

    else if((this.totalSales > ((SalePerson) o).getTotalSales()))
    {
        count = 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Which two fields?

Comment: lastname and totalsales

Comment: so last names should equal and comparison based on total sales?

Comment: its like sorting both lastname and totalsales in ascending order

Comment: In which order do you want to compare? I mean which field should be compared first?

Comment: oh the totalsales

Comment: if  `lastname` are equal then check for `toalSales`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement `Comparable` interface, it is unecassary to throw `ClassCastException` since `o` has to be `SalePerson`, otherwise you will get a compile error.

You can do it this way:

```
public class SalePerson implements Comparable<SalePerson>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SalePerson o) {
        int totalSalesCompare = Integer.compare(this.totalSales, o.getTotalSales());
        return totalSalesCompare == 0 ? this.lastName.compareTo(o.getLastName()) 
                : totalSalesCompare;

    }
}
```

Also, the `compareTo` is suggested to work with `equals` and `hashCode`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof SalePerson)) {
        return false;
    }
    return Integer.compare(Integer.compare(this.totalSales, o.getTotalSales())) == 0
            && this.lastName.equals(o.getLastName());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.lastName.hashCode() * 31 + this.totalSales;
}
```